# Did Kim Jong Un have his Uncle's entire family executed?

Tags: north-korea

Jang Song-thaek - Kim Jong Un's uncle who was executed in 2013.

According to this article ([Entire family of Kim Jong-Un's uncle executed in N. Korea](https://www.rt.com/news/korean-leader-family-slayed-213/)), Kim Jong Un had all his blood relations killed.

How likely is this true? Some of the people killed were diplomats working overseas who seemed to voluntarily fly back to North Korea to be executed.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Where did you read that some diplomats returned to be executed?

Comment: @Oddthinking - "Both diplomats were recalled back to North Korea in early December and executed "

Comment: This article also says they were "recalled to Pyongyang in early December", shortly before Jang was executed http://english.sina.com/world/2014/0125/666777.html I think it's what the Russia Today report is based on

Comment: You'll never find this out. You haven't defined "family" nor the criteria for having the family executed? The problem with the DPRK is often that the party's actions are a manifestation of Kim's will without any direct line.

Comment: @Evan Carroll could explain, please, `a manifestation of Kim's will without any direct line`? I think  I got you, but to be sure...

Comment: @RS I doubt any dictator has ever had anyone executed per se. That's not how they do this. That's why you have kangaroo courts and plausible deniability and the like. The west does this the same way: Assange isn't a journalist and he raped someone; and Abdulrahman al-Awlaki and his sister weren't the intended targets of the laser guided drones.

Comment: Russia, China, North Korea. There's no limit how far they will try to publish and disseminate fake news. The North Korean leader has been declared dead numerous times. We've been fed news stories that he had people fed to dogs. Executed by anti-aircraft guns. Only for them to reappear later. It's ironic how a society like North Korea that uses propaganda so purposedely. Somehow their propganda doesn't even come to close to ours. We always say North Koreans are brainwashed. Yet we don't even consider whether we are worse.

Answer (score 2):

## "Entire family"

From a western American perspective, your wife would probably be under the umbrella of "entire family". Jang's wife was not executed. Her name is [Kim Kyong-hui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Kyong-hui): she's the aunt of Kim Jong-un.

Comment: Why would you think that's a western american perspective?

Comment: Presumably nephews are also not part of the "Entire Family".